# It is not possible to pass a typed parameter to type r

Tags: python, typer

I have this code

```
import typer

app = typer.Typer()


class Parametrs:
    one: int
    two: str


@app.command()
def calib(parametrs: Parametrs):
    print(f"One: {parametrs.one}, Two: {parametrs.two}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

when I try to send a command to the console, I get an error

Then i get this error

**RuntimeError: Type not yet supported: <class '**main**.Parametrs'>**

Answer (score 0):

Yup you're exactly right it's a `typer` thing. But! We may be able to make this work. Could you do something like this?

```py
import typer

app = typer.Typer()

class Parametrs:
    def __init__(self, one: int, two: str):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two

@app.command()
def calib(one: int, two: str):
    parametrs = Parametrs(one, two)
    print(f"One: {parametrs.one}, Two: {parametrs.two}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a [custom parser](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/parameter-types/custom-types/) to teach `typer` how to parse your type. Assuming `Parameters` is required,

```
import typer
from typing import Annotated

class Parameters:
    ...

def parse_parameters(input_data: str) -> Parameters:
    # Construct a parameters instance from the input parameter here
    ...

@app.command()
def calib(parameters: Annotated[Parameters, typer.Argument(parser=parse_parameters)]):
    ...
```